# Como coloco una imagen de fondo desde CSS sin introducirla en el HTML?

Tags: html, css, imagen

He tratado de colocar una imagen de fondo fija, que solo el texto se desplace,
no puedo colocar la imagen desde el archivo .CSS, pero desde el HTML si.

Alguna forma de manejarlo desde el .CSS?

```css
.titulito{
  font-family: 'Stylish', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.fondito{
  background: url("../img/flower.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stylish&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fondito"></div>
    <div class="titulito">
      <h1>Atraves de ti</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agrega algo que ocupe espacio dentro del div "fondito" en tu HTML, de lo contrario añade a la clase "fondito" la propiedad `height` en tu CSS.

Answer (score 1):

con overflow:scroll en la clase fondito

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple). Y si, se que no hay mucho para explicar, pero el sistema la considera de baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

que tal si la clase "fondito" se la asignas a la etiqueta body?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stylish&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="fondito">
<div class="titulito">
  <h1>Atraves de ti</h1>
</div>
```